# I am getting the error Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am new to vue and have been trying to follow a tutorial for adding Axios, but I end up getting the error and I cannot find a way to fix it.
I am running it on localhost:3000 but I tried to go back to 8080 and it is still showing me the problem, it would be amazing if you guys could give me some tips.

Here is the error

```
xhr.js?b50d:210 POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:210
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:15
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:58
request @ Axios.js?0a06:112
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:147
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
_callee$ @ Register.vue?0103:55
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:294
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21
handleSubmit @ Register.vue?0103:55
submit @ Register.vue?01bd:11
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 404"

found in

---> <Register> at src/components/Register.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1893
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1848
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1865
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1865
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js?b50d:66:1)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1897
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1848
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1865
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1865
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
```

for register in inspect
when right something it doesn't work

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

But in general, this shows it's okay

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/register
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <h3> Sign up </h3>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type ="text" class ="form-control" v-model ="first_name" palceholder="First Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" v-model ="last_name" placeholder= "Last Name"/>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" v-model ="email" placeholder= "Email"/>
    </div>
    <div class= "form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" v-model ="password" placeholder= "Password"/>
    </div>

     <div class= "form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" class ="form-control" v-model="confirm_password" placeholder= " Confirm Password"/>
    </div>

    <button class= "btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
    
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    
    name: 'Register',

    data() {

        return {

            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirm_password: ''
            
        }
    },
    methods:  {

        async handleSubmit() {

            const response = await axios.post('register', {

                first_name: this.first_name,
                last_name: this.last_name,
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password,
                confirm_password: this.confirm_password


            });

            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    })
  }
```

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Sorry this isn't formatted right I have been trying to figure it out for days and cannot seem to work it out

Comment: It looks like you've created a custom axios instance with a baseURL, but you are not using it. Import it into your component instead of default axios.

Comment: i imported it and it still shows the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

As @Romalex already commented, you created an axios object with a base Url, but you don't use it.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
});

export default api;
```

Give the object a name, export it, and use it in your application instead of the axios object

Example:

```
async getData() {
  return await api.get('/data/1');
}
```

Comment: i did what you told me and i am still getting the error, ```             const response = await api.post('register', data);
             console.log(response) ```

Comment: @ShadmanShafin check the availability of your server api (post request http://localhost:3000/register) using postman or another tool

Comment: i tried using postman and it doesnt work, i am reallly stressing about this any way you can take a look at it please?